# Set multiple datasets with similar names in sas

Tags: sas, datastep

Suppose I have a varying number of datasets in my work environment, but all of which start with a similar name: name_abc, name_efg, name_1ky, etc. The datasets have the same variables and characteristics, and I want to set them all into one dataset.

```
data bigdataset;
    set [all datasets that begin with name_];
run;
```

Is there a way I can do this in SAS without typing all the datasets? I need this to be flexible with the number of datasets available in work environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a **variable name wildcard `:`**

```
data bigdataset;
 set name_:;
run;
```

> A colon following a variable name prefix selects any variable whose
>   name starts with that prefix. This  ability of the  colon along with
>   some simple naming standards enables the programmer to manage
>   temporary variables better,  format many variables quicker, determine
>   unknown number of variables, clean up macro generated datasets, and 
>   shorten the code for variety of PROCS. For example
>
> ```
> data ADLB;
> set  lb:;
> ```
>
> This DATA step reads all the data sets in the WORK  library that begin with LB. Also, when the programmer
>   coded  this step, he/she did not need to know how many dataset are
>   read, only that he/she wants to read all of the dataset  with a
>   particular prefix. Both colon and dash lists also work with the MERGE
>   statement.

Quoted from [Using SAS Colon Effectively](http://www.pharmasug.org/proceedings/2012/TA/PharmaSUG-2012-TA05.pdf)

Comment: Umm, those edits entirely missed Reeza's initial point.  `prefix:` was correct.  prefix = the prefix common to the datasets...

Comment: @skobaljic, if you added that quote from a source like the documentation, please add the reference to that source as well.

Comment: Added, hope it is useful to someone.

Answer (score 1):

This will work whether or not the data sets have a common prefix. Of course for your situation the [COLON](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi26/p073-26.pdf) modifier is a really good solution.

```
PROC SQL noprint;
    SELECT CATS(libname,".",memname) into :DSNS separated by " "
    FROM DICTIONARY.TABLES 
    WHERE UPCASE(LIBNAME)="YOUR_LIBNAME";
QUIT;
%Put DATA SETS: &DSNS;

Data BIGDATASET;
    Set &dsns;
Run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use colon modifier, e.g. below will combine all datasets in sashelp library that start with prdsal :

```
data all ;
 set sashelp.prdsal: ;
run;
```